# Moon CSR example file

Tags: leaflet

I'm trying to make an moon CRS JS file, but my géo-mathematics are not very good, in fact, i don't understand ! But i've a to do a scientifics experience, can you help me ? Peraphs it can be done with just configuration.
Let me explain, i need to set magnetic north pole on moon map.
I use moon map from: [https://cartocdn-gusc.global.ssl.fastly.net/opmbuilder/api/v1/map/named/opm-moon-basemap-v0-1/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png](https://cartocdn-gusc.global.ssl.fastly.net/opmbuilder/api/v1/map/named/opm-moon-basemap-v0-1/all/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png)

I need to change pole north, because when i set a marker to [0,0], the marker appear not where i want. In other manner, i need to move north pole where i want. On earth, and moon if i want.

After that, i ll set pointer from public data and whatch what it done. On moon, on earth, on personal photo.

[image: screenshot example]

Comment: Start by choosing a suitable lunar coordinate reference system. Do read https://www.reddit.com/r/QGIS/comments/qs0c22/crs_for_the_lunar_south_pole/ . Research what CRS is suitable for the tiles you're using.

Comment: This Stack website is geared towards coding.  Your question does not show any code and would be more suitable for the Stack website that focused on Geographic Information Systems.    https://gis.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

thanks i'll try to find it

```
const map = L.map('map', {
    // crs: L.CRS.EPSGMoonMercator, // MoonMercator
    // crs: L.CRS.EPSGMoonSphericalMercator, // MoonMercator
    // crs: L.CRS.EPSG3395, // Mercator
    crs: L.CRS.EPSG3857, // SphericalMercator
    center: [-70,0],
    zoom: 4,
    // minZoom: 3,
    // maxZoom: 8,

});
```